# invalid email and return to begining

Tags: python

I'm new to python I got a question that might be easy but i can't get it.
i wanted to make aprogram that user gives email as username and password as password ,the program should check if email is in corect format and if its not it **should print something and get email again** so i used regex (Im giving this inputs to database and i thought using LIKE query but i don't think that might help)

so whats the problem with my code?!it keeps wrong email

```
import re

regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'
def check(email):
    if (re.fullmatch(regex, email)):
       
        return
 
    else:
        print("corect format is like amireza@gmail.com")
        return
                
        
while __name__ == '__main__':

    username = input()
    check(username)
     
password = input()
```

Comment: Your example of "amireza@gmail.com" matches the pattern juts fine; what is the problem you are having?

Comment: `while __name__ == '__main__':` is not what you want though; replace `while` with `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a working code for you:

```py
import re

regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'
def check(email):
    if (re.fullmatch(regex, email)):
        return True
 
    else:
        print("invalid input! correct format is like amireza@gmail.com")
        return False
        
                
        
while __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        username = input("please enter email\n")
        if check(username) is True:
            break
    password = input("please enter password\n")
    break

print("username: %s, password: %s" % (username, password))
```

key correction:

- your helper should return a boolean which lets you know if the input is legit or not. thus I returned a boolean to outside scope

one more thing: since you run it as a standalone script, the outermost while condition (`while __name__ == '__main__'`) will always be `True`, which means you have to `break` out of it when you want to end your program execution. For simplicity I'd suggest using `if __name__ == '__main__'` instead

Comment: thanks for your guide

Answer (score 0):

You could change your function `check` to return a boolean output that tells you whether the check was successful, as in

```
def check(email):
    if (re.fullmatch(regex, email)):
       
        return True
 
    else:
        print("corect format is like amireza@gmail.com")
        return False
```

And then add a loop to your main code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    username = input()
    while not check(username):
        username = input()
```

Note that I did not actually run your code, but this should work.

EDIT: Heh, right, as the other answer explains, you should change your `while` into an `if`, I edited my code correspondingly.

Comment: the code without `break` statements will always keep asking for username

Comment: I've just posted a working version, fyi :)

Comment: @AliYılmaz Right, thank you. After posting I read your answer and quickly realized my (and OP's) mistake. :)